# editar valores por json cake php

Tags: php, cakephp

tengo esto como httpclient en cakephp tengo este valor en mi index para que sea enviado a editar, todo aqui bien.

```
<?php foreach ($valor->articles as $article): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?= $article->id ?></td>

    <td><?= $article->title ?></td>

    <td><?= $article->body ?></td>


    <td>
        <?= $this->Form->postLink(
            'Delete',
            ['action' => 'delete', $article->id],
            ['confirm' => 'Are you sure?'])
        ?>
        <?= $this->Html->link('Edit', ['action' => 'edit', $article->id]) ?>//aca lo envio a editar
    </td>

</tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

aca al mostrar en pantalla del edit por un var_dump.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya puedo enviar el valor, como ven en la pagina se ve el valor y asi tengo el controlador.

```
public function edit($id = null)
{
    $http = new Client();
    $response = $http->post('http://localhost/paginaws/articles/edit', []);
    $json = $response->json;
    $json = $response->body;
    $valores = json_decode($id);

    $this->set(compact(['valores']));
```

hasta aca estoy intentando que se  pueda ver todo sus valores del array y que se pueda editar, una accesoria.

Comment: ¿Intentaste hacerlo como dice la [documentación](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#updating-data)?

Comment: si por su puesto pero no hay una documentacion que es por PUT

Comment: Con Http Client lo haces con `$client->put()`, no queda muy claro lo que quieres hacer

Comment: lo que quiero es editar un valor especifico seleccionando un valor pero como no se hace desde informacion local pues debo enviar eso a un rest.

Comment: Entiendo, pero Client solo hace las peticiones, lo necesario para actualizar en la base de datos lo debes hacer en `http://localhost/paginaws/articles/edit`

Comment: Si creaste un formulario con el FormHelper podrías obtenerla con `$this->request->getData()` o `$this->request->data` y la pasas como argumento en Client

Comment: ya tengo implementado  $this->request->getData() en mi rest pero quiero es consumirlo editando valores.

Comment: ¿Y como llegan los valores que quieres editar hasta la función que consume el REST?

Comment: estoy realizando esto 'public function edit($id)
 {
 $data = $this->request->input('json_decode');
 $http = new Client();
    $response = $http->post(
   'http://localhost/paginaws/articles/edit',
   json_encode($data),
   ['type' => 'json']
 );
 $json = $response->json;
 $json = $response->body;
 $valor = json_decode($json);

 $this->set(compact(['valor']));


 }
'

Comment: Si, entiendo todo eso, pero mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo llegan ahí los valores que deseas cambiar?. Por ejemplo: si quiero cambiar el nombre, ¿el usuario donde escribe ese nuevo nombre?

Comment: llega como metodo get la ruta es asi'http://localhost/paginaws/articles/edit/56.json'

Comment: ¿Osea están llegando con query strings?

Comment: no esta solo como array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investigando supe que al enviar un valor debe ser como post y me estava enviando como get.